# recovering previously printed files from many years ago

Tags: pdf, printing, recovery

I am using Windows 10. I am trying to get a copy of a file I printed out in around 2016 or so. It was a page/document accessed from a website, and I don't think I specifically saved the file before printing it. It would most likely have been a .pdf. I 'lost' the hard copy and havent been able to find it online again. Is there anywhere on my PC that the image of the file would have been saved? And if so, how can I access the file? I'm prepared to look through many old files if necessary...

Thanks in advance.
Sue

Comment: If you saved it, then Search will find it by name, or more long-winded, by file type then date. If you didn't save it, it will be long, long gone.

Comment: If you set the Content flag for PDF in Index Options, then you can search your drive using text you believe to be in the file. If not found, then it is gone.

Comment: powergrep has a free trial period of 15 days and can search text inside PDF files.

Comment: Thank you all for your ideas. I'm going to look into the powergrep option as well as Web Archive, although I don't know anything about either. I'm looking up Web Archive now. For clarification, I have access to the website where I originally got the file to print way back when, in case that's needed to check the web archive. Anyway, thank you all for your suggestions and help! _ Sue